# Lipschitizianity of the square root of a positive $C^2$ function

Tags: analysis, continuity, lipschitz-functions, holder-spaces

I was trying to solve this exercise.
Let  $f\in C^2(\mathbb{R})$ a strictly positive function such that $f''$ is bounded. Then prove that $\sqrt{f}$ is Lipschitz.
A first idea was to prove that it's first derivative is bounded, but i find the expression $\dfrac{f'}{\sqrt{f}}$ which gave me no informations, also deriving again this expression i'm not able to use the bound on the second derivative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $x$ and $y$ we have

$$0\leq f(y)=f(x)+\int_{x}^y f'(s)ds=f(x)+\int_x^y[ f'(x)+\int_{x}^s f''(t)]dtds\\ \leq f(x)+(y-x)f'(x)+|y-x|^2/2\max_{\mathbb{R}}|f''|$$

Now let $y-x=\pm\sqrt{f(x)}$ and you obtain that

$$0\leq (1+C)f(x)\pm\sqrt{f(x)}f'(x)\\ \Rightarrow  \frac{|f'(x)|}{\sqrt{f(x)}}\leq (1+C)$$

This proves the claim for strictly positive $f$, as you noted. But you can also deduct the claim for $f\geq 0$ by approximating it with $f_\varepsilon:=f+\varepsilon$ and then taking limits (this taking limits requires further arguments!)

Comment: Very brilliant, i would never think to a similar solution. For me it rains from the sky.

Comment: As you saw from my previous (now deleted) answer, it did not actually fall from the sky, but took quite a while of playing around. To make it more intuitive than in the version written down: after you have the first two lines (which simply combine Taylor expansion with the two pieces of information that are given) you first isolate what you want to be bounded, i.e. you take the term $(y-x)f'(x)$ to the LHS and divide by $y-x$. Now my choice of $y-x$ is simply the one that gives the best possible bound (with $y-x=:t$ what you have is $f'(x)\leq f(x)/t+t^2\quad\forall t$. now minimize in $t$)